# Beautiful soup + requests. Вопрос по find_all()

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

На сайте есть несколько классов 'карточек', лутаю все с помощью find_all().
Как теперь вытащить одну конкретную карточку?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,"html.parser")
value = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-ovtrou')
```

Вывод:

```
[<div class="css-ovtrou" data-bn-type="text" style="direction:ltr">$20,666.64</div>, <div class="css-ovtrou" data-bn-type="text" style="direction:ltr">$1,572.08</div>, <div class="css-ovtrou" data-bn-type="text" style="direction:ltr">$1.00</div>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте цикл `for`, чтобы пройтись по всем "карточкам" или `find`.

С циклом:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,"html.parser")
value = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-ovtrou')
for div in value:
    print(div)
    print(div.text)
```

С find (найдёте первый попавшийся с тегом div):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,"html.parser")
value = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-ovtrou')
res = value.find('div')
print(res.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно код карточки сделать строкой(str(карточка)), а потом значение брать с помощью среза, т.е. допустим, нам надо спарсить первую карточку. Тогда код будет такой:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,"html.parser")
value = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-ovtrou')[0]    # В [] помещаем индекс карты
card = str(value[66:-6])    # Обрезаем данные
print(card)
```

Comment: @CrazyElf а я как делаю? я же вроде в value как раз и беру элемент, потом в card обрезаю.

Comment: А, ну да. Не туда посмотрел. Хотя всё-равно через `str` не очень, но тут я не прав был, удалю комментарий )

Comment: А если нам нужно получить значение тега, атрибута или само имя тега? Срезы – затея не очень.